# Mysql syntax help

Tags: mysql

Hi i am new to mysql and i have made the following statement

```
UPDATE parent, chill SET parent.iod=chill.iod WHERE  parent.id=chill.id
```

what i want to do is copy all the iod's from chill to parent where id should be matched.

But the result is that all the iod updated are set to 11 rather than iod's in chill.

iod's is of type

```
BIGINT
```

Is there ant mistake in the syntax or anything that i am doing wrong?

help with little explanation appreciated.

Comment: what's the output of `SELECT DISTINCT iod FROM chill;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql update syntax for join tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> The preceding example shows an inner join that uses the comma operator, but multiple-table UPDATE statements can use any type of join permitted in SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.

try the following (although your example should work as well):

```
UPDATE parent
INNER JOIN chill
ON parent.id = chill.id
SET parent.iod = chill.iod
```

Comment: Why an inner join? I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: @ThinkCode: he only wants rows with matching IDs → `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Is this any different? UPDATE parent, chill SET parent.iod = chill.iod WHERE parent.id = chill.id;

Comment: @ThinkCode: shouldn't be, that's why I mentioned in my answer »(although your example should work as well)«

Comment: Hey thanks a lot ..well actually it was my mistake i declared it as a bigint rather it needs to be declared as a varchar.:)

Comment: John, friendly advise : paste the 'DESC' of the table from next time on, it will make it easy for us to answer!